# How to pass data between Forms in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkbox, datalist

I have form using `datalist` and fulfilled with `checkboxes`. Like below

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListTest" runat="server" OnPreRender="PreTes">
        <ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server"></asp:Label>  <!-- Telephone, Bussines System -->                                    
        </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblsubheader" runat="server" /></td>    <!-- Oracle, EPM, CRM (Muncul di Form) -->
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="idJenisAccess" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id_jenis_access") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="subhd" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("sub_jenis") %>' /> <!-- Oracle, EPM, CRM (nama sub jenis) --> 
        <asp:HiddenField ID="id_access" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id_access") %>' /><!-- Output = ACT5, ACBS1 -->
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hd" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("nama_jenis") %>' /><!-- Output = Telephone, Bussines System -->
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdstatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("status") %>' /> <!-- Output = 1 or 0 -->
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCountryName" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("nama_access") %>' /> <!-- Output = Local, Handphone, Project -->
        <asp:TextBox ID="testme" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" /> <!-- Output = Textbox for all -->            
       </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblReason" runat="server" Visible="false" text="Reason : "/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReason" runat="server" Visible="false" />    
        </td>                   
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Visible="false" text="Description : "/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
        </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

And the code behind form, to get data from database is like this below.

```
private void ShowDataList()
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "Select access.id_access as 'id_access', access.status as 'status' , access.nama_access, jenis_access.id_jenis_access as 'id_jenis_access' ,jenis_access.nama_jenis_access as 'nama_jenis', sub_jenis.nama_sub_jenis as 'sub_jenis',sub_jenis.id_sub_jenis "+
                 "FROM access LEFT JOIN detil_access ON access.id_access = detil_access.id_access "+
                 "LEFT JOIN jenis_access ON detil_access.id_jenis_access = jenis_access.id_jenis_access "+
                 "LEFT JOIN sub_jenis ON detil_access.id_sub_jenis = sub_jenis.id_sub_jenis "+
                 "ORDER BY jenis_access.nama_jenis_access";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    DataListTest.DataSource = dt;
    DataListTest.DataBind();
}
```

And this is my `PreRender Datalist`, I called it `PreTest`. And it is also my code to show the data as `checkboxes`.

```
protected void PreTes(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temp = ""; 
    string subtemp ="";
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataListTest.Items)
    {
        Label objLabel = item.FindControl("lblHeader") as Label; /* Output = Telepon, Business System (nama jenis access) */
        Label subjenis = item.FindControl("lblsubheader") as Label; /* Output = Oracle, CRM, EPM (nama sub jenis access) */
        Label lblreason = (Label)item.FindControl("lblReason"); /* Output = Reason : (label reaseon) */
        Label lbldescription = (Label)item.FindControl("lblDescription"); /* Output = Description : (label Description) */
        TextBox txtOther = item.FindControl("testme") as TextBox; /* Output = textbox except reason and description */
        TextBox txtReason = item.FindControl("txtReason") as TextBox; /* Output = textbox on Reason */
        TextBox txtDescription = item.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox; /* Output = textbox on Description */
        CheckBox objName = item.FindControl("cbCountryName") as CheckBox; /* Output = Local, Internet, Email (nama access) */
        HiddenField objHD = item.FindControl("hd") as HiddenField; /* Output = Telpon, Business System (if deleted, nama jenis will be show up every single access name) */
        HiddenField subobjHD = item.FindControl("subhd") as HiddenField;
        HiddenField id_access = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("id_access");
        HiddenField id_jenis = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("idJenisAccess");
        HiddenField status = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdstatus");


        if (temp != objHD.Value)
        {                                                     
             if (objHD.Value=="Others" && id_access.Value == "ACT5")
             {
                 lblreason.Visible = true;
                 txtReason.Visible = true;
                 lbldescription.Visible = true;
                 txtDescription.Visible = true;
             }
             temp = objHD.Value;
             objLabel.Text = temp + "<br/>";
        }
        if (subtemp != subobjHD.Value)
        {
            subtemp = subobjHD.Value;
            subjenis.Text = subtemp+"<br/>";
        }
        if (status.Value == "1")
        {
            txtOther.Visible = true;                                
        }            
    }
}
```

And after All, I want to save the data from form into database. I mean, after user check some checkboxes. I wan to Insert all to database. and this is my code to insert the data

```
private void InsertActivationDetail()
{
    //Mengambil nilai idActivation
    int MaxActivationId = GetGenerateActivationID();
    //

    foreach (DataListItem objitem in DataListTest.Items)
    {

        /* To get data from the form , then insert into database */
        CheckBox cbCountryName = (CheckBox)objitem.FindControl("cbCountryName");
        HiddenField id_access = (HiddenField)objitem.FindControl("id_access");
        HiddenField id_jenis_access = (HiddenField)objitem.FindControl("idJenisAccess");
        TextBox txtOther = objitem.FindControl("testme") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtreason = objitem.FindControl("txtReason") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtdescription = objitem.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox;
        /* Get data end, then Inserting the data (below) */

        /*Check if datalist is null or not*/
        if (objitem !=null)
        {
            /*if not nul, then check the checkboxes, is null or not*/
            if (cbCountryName.Checked == true)
            {                    
                /*if not null, then insert the data */
                conn.Open();                    
                     sql = "INSERT INTO detil_activation (id_activation_access, id_jenis_access, id_access, " +
                          "keterangan, reason, description) " +
                          "VALUES ('" +
                          MaxActivationId + "', '"+ id_jenis_access.Value +"', '" + id_access.Value + "','"+
                          txtOther.Text +"','"+txtreason.Text+"','"+txtdescription.Text+"')";                    
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                conn.Close();
                /* Inserting data is done */ 
            }
        }            
    }       
}
```

And my question is,

how to send all selected `checkboxes` by user into the other web form ?

Example:

when user check some checkboxes and click submit, then I insert all data which checked on `checkbox` like `id_access` , `id_jenis` , and text on textbox `(ID ="testme")` into database.

All process will happen when user click button submit and when submit button is clicked, I want all data from checked `checkboxes` are show on the other page (page's name = "SendingActivation").

like "You choose : id_access id_jenis (enter) id_access id_jenis (enter) id_access id_jenis (as much as the selected data).

FYI : I'm newbie here also c# programming, so please help me step by step

Comment: Do you want all data on other page like checkboxes and value of textboxes also or only the checcked checkboxes ?

Comment: Can you get data from database on basis of id_jenis_access and id_access ?

Comment: yes, I can get data basis of id_jenis_acces and id_access
and I want to show it.
exemple : user check 3 access in 2 category(jenis_access's name) lets say there are 2 category. Internet and Telephone. Category Internet has 3 access lets say VPN, Email, E-Requisition. Category Telephone has 2 access lets say Local, Interlocal. on category Internet, user check email and category telepon all checked. in page 2 should "you choose email, local , interlocal" like that. understand?

Answer (score 1):

Their are lots of methods are available to achieve this;

- **Application Variables**
- **Session Variables**
- **Response.Redirect**
- **Cookiess**
- **Using POST method**

**Application Variables**

Passing:

```
Application["id_access"] = "A0123";
```

Accessing:

```
string id_access = Application["id_access"].ToString();
```

**Session Variables**

Assigning:

```
Session["id_access"] = "A0123";
```

Reading:

```
 string id_access =  Session["id_access"];
```

**Response.Redirect**

Passing:

```
Response.Redirect("SendingActivation.aspx?id_access="A0123");
```

Accessing:

```
  string id_access = Request.QueryString["id_access"];
```

**Cookiess**

Passing:

```
HttpCookie id_access= new HttpCookie("Name");
id_access.Value="A0123";
```

Accessing:

```
string id_access= Request.Cookies["Name"].Value;
```

**Using POST method**

Passing:

In the source page `button` control that post values when the form is submitted.Set the `PostBackUrl` property for the control to the URL of the page to which you want to post the ASP.NET Web page

Accessing:

```
string id_access= Request.Form["ControlID"];
```

Comment: so you mean, I should add 1 of 5 method on my application?
in page 1 or page 2 ?
and where should i add all that "Accessing" ?
new function ? or on load ?

Comment: and, my data is not fix. I mean, I don't know what id_access that user choose. so how i get it dynamically ?

Comment: You can use anyone among the 5. assigning/ passing should be in the first page accessing is in the redirected page

Comment: and what about the data ?
my data is not fix like id_access = "A0123". it must be dynamic with whatever user choose on checkbox

Comment: use  checkbox.text instead for static data like "A0123"

Comment: checkbox.text is for name right ? can it get the id too ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your InsertActivationDetail method like this.I have created a string in which MaxActivationId will be saved i assume MaxActivatinoId will be unique whenver you insert data in database.And in next page you will receive this id as Query string and get data from database on basis of MaxActivation id and display it in your page.

```
private void InsertActivationDetail()
{
    //Mengambil nilai idActivation
    int MaxActivationId = GetGenerateActivationID();
    //
    string id = "";
    foreach (DataListItem objitem in DataListTest.Items)
    {

        /* To get data from the form , then insert into database */
        CheckBox cbCountryName = (CheckBox)objitem.FindControl("cbCountryName");
        HiddenField id_access = (HiddenField)objitem.FindControl("id_access");
        HiddenField id_jenis_access = (HiddenField)objitem.FindControl("idJenisAccess");
        TextBox txtOther = objitem.FindControl("testme") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtreason = objitem.FindControl("txtReason") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtdescription = objitem.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox;
        /* Get data end, then Inserting the data (below) */

        /*Check if datalist is null or not*/
        if (objitem != null)
        {
            /*if not nul, then check the checkboxes, is null or not*/
            if (cbCountryName.Checked == true)
            {
                /*if not null, then insert the data */
                conn.Open();
                sql = "INSERT INTO detil_activation (id_activation_access, id_jenis_access, id_access, " +
                     "keterangan, reason, description) " +
                     "VALUES ('" +
                     MaxActivationId + "', '" + id_jenis_access.Value + "', '" + id_access.Value + "','" +
                     txtOther.Text + "','" + txtreason.Text + "','" + txtdescription.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                ids += MaxActivationId.ToString() + ",";
                /* Inserting data is done */
            }
        }
    }
    id = MaxActivationId.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("yourpage?maxID=" + id);
}
```

Comment: it can't be. because MaxActivationId is in my table can repeat. i need the id_access and id_jenis_access directly ? can I ?

Comment: As you said that user can check checkboxes as many as user wants so all id_Access and id_jenis_access will be saved against MaxActivationId.So you can get all checked checkboxes against MAxActivationId.

Comment: my column table is like this
id_detail      | id_activation_access | id_access | id_jenis_Access
AUTOincerement     MaxActivationId     id_Access      id_jenis
ex:
id_detail      | id_activation_access | id_access | id_jenis_Access
   1                     1                407             12
   2                     1                409             12
   3                     1                305              8
   4                     1                201             15

like that. i can't make format table in comment. hope you understand

Comment: All data will be inserted for a single MaxActivationId so you can get all data from MAxActivationId which is inserted for checked checkboxes.Just run a query in SQl and you will get the result. If still a problem let me know.

Comment: yaaa, it works. but, now how to show my data on page 2, if it is more than 1 value ?

Comment: Use loop on the data which you get from database like this for(var i=0;i<data.Length;i++){//show your data here}.If still you are not clear please let me know.

Comment: why my MaxActivationId on passing statemen is null ?
it didn't catch the id

Comment: I have changed the last line please update it at your end and then check again.

Comment: @azalikaayla you can contact me on minhas06@hotmail.com i will look into your problem in detail.Contact me tomorrow i will be free in morning.